# Not defined error while creating choose your own adventure

Tags: python

```
def game():
    print("You wake up in a field. Alone. You wander around and find a small shed with a large, steel padlock on it. \n Around the shed, you find three items. You find: \n A) A shovel \n B) A vial of Nitric Acid \n C) A crowbar \n Which item do you choose to utilize? (A, B, or C)")
    scene1 = input().upper()
    if scene1 == 'A':
        print("You dig a hole. You keep digging until you find yourself stuck. \n You struggle to find a way out when suddenly... \n your shovel hits something hard. You dig it up and you find a toolbox - it looks like it\'s from the World War Three era. \n You open it and find: \n A) A stick of dynamite \n B) Bird feed \n C) A rope ladder \n Which item do you choose (A, B, or C)?")
    if scene1 == 'B':
        print("You carefully pick up the vial of Nitric Acid and carry it to the padlock. \nSuddenly, a strong gust of wind blows the vial out of your hands where it breaks and splashes on you. \nYou are now suffering from third-degree chemical burns. You die... Do you want to play again? (YES or NO)")
        endgame = input()
while endgame == 'yes':
    game()
```

Comment: I think it'd be easier to help if you were to post the error message and give an explanation of what you've done to debug/are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

I ran the code as is. You never defined the endgame variable so the while loop fails when it first tries to run.

Set the variable before the loop starts and make sure to use the global endgame variable:

```
endgame = 'yes'
def game():
    global endgame 
    print("You wake up in a field. Alone. You wander around and find a small shed with a large, steel padlock on it. \n Around the shed, you find three items. You find: \n A) A shovel \n B) A vial of Nitric Acid \n C) A crowbar \n Which item do you choose to utilize? (A, B, or C)")
    scene1 = input().upper()
    if scene1 == 'A':
        print("You dig a hole. You keep digging until you find yourself stuck. \n You struggle to find a way out when suddenly... \n your shovel hits something hard. You dig it up and you find a toolbox - it looks like it\'s from the World War Three era. \n You open it and find: \n A) A stick of dynamite \n B) Bird feed \n C) A rope ladder \n Which item do you choose (A, B, or C)?")
    if scene1 == 'B':
        print("You carefully pick up the vial of Nitric Acid and carry it to the padlock. \nSuddenly, a strong gust of wind blows the vial out of your hands where it breaks and splashes on you. \nYou are now suffering from third-degree chemical burns. You die... Do you want to play again? (YES or NO)")
        endgame = input()
while endgame.lower() == 'yes':
    game()
```